# How to read from a file using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c

I have Uploaded a file into server and I want to read the data from that file and insert data into the oracle. I am using a list for taking the data from the file and Data is reading from this List. No problem with my code. It  reads completely and data's are inserted into the oracle table Locally.. But After Hosting the data's not completely inserted to the table..After inserting some data it become stuck.

Comment: Do you mean.. it's working fine in development, but not when you deploy it to production or some other environment ?

Comment: Yeah its work fine in development.. But after Hosting for testing only some data's will be inserted into the Database...

Comment: There may be a server error on which you host your application, may be some setting required on IIS. Some sort of permissions.